# Fill Datagridview row by row from a datatable by manually mapping columns

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm a VB.Net coder, but trying to approach C# programming
In VB.NET I can write like this without any hassle

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1 'dt is datatable
    dgv.Rows.Add()
    dgv.Rows(i).Cells("Sno").Value = i + 1
    dgv.Rows(i).Cells("itemcode").Value = dt.Rows(i)("itemcode").ToString.Trim
    dgv.Rows(i).Cells("itemname").Value = dt.Rows(i)("itemname")
Next
```

But when I code in C#

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count-1; i++) //dt is datatable
{
    DG.Rows.Add();
    DG.Rows(i).Cells("Sr").Value = i + 1;
    DG.Rows(i).Cells("Itemcode").Value = dt.rows(i)("itemcode");
}
```

`DG.Rows(i).Cells("Sr").Value = i + 1;` gives error

> Non-invocable member 'DataGridView.Rows' cannot be used like a
>   method.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# you should use brackets `[]` instead of parenthesis `()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    DG.Rows.Add();
    DG.Rows[i].Cells["Sr"].Value = i + 1;
    DG.Rows[i].Cells["Itemcode"].Value = dt.Rows[i]["itemcode"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Using [] brackets instead of () :

e.g.

```
 DG.Rows[i].Cells["Sr"].Value = i + 1;
```

instead of

```
 DG.Rows(i).Cells("Sr").Value = i + 1;
```

Comment: Hi, How is this different from my answer? :)

Comment: Sorry! I was posting the answer and you beat me to it :)

Comment: Also the `Cells("Sr")` should be `Cells["Sr"]` too.

Comment: Thanks forgot that one.:)

Comment: @S.Akbari & Adds : Thank you both for the prompt help. Just wanted to know a last thing, is C# more complex/vast than VB.net? If so would it take time for a VB.net coder to adapt C#

Comment: @RahulKurup Have a look at this link http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html